# How to find the list of words in the corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here I have to find words which are in the list c, this words are present in the corpus rows or not.

I am expecting the answer as [1,3,2,4,1,1,4,1,4]

means word "and" is present in row 3 hence answer "1"

word "document" is present in the row1,row2 and row4 hence answer is "3" and so on

kindly correct my program, also if you have any easiest one then also suggest. Thank you

```
corpus= [
         'this is the first document',            #row1
         'this document is the second document',  #row2
         'and this is the third one',             #row3
         'is this the first document',            #row4
    ]

c=['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']

a=[]
count=0

for words in c:
  a.append(count)
  count=0
  for row in corpus:
    if words in row:
      count=count+1
print(a)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I don't understand why you `append(count)` as start - you should do it after inner `for`-loop

Comment: yes, I use python tutor to understand the each step answers

Comment: and what you get with `pythontutor`? Alll your problem is that you use `append()` in wrong place - you have to use it after `for`-loop. That's all

Comment: ok , I will try

Answer (score 0):

Alll your problem is that you use `append()` in wrong place.

You have to use it after `for`-loop.

```
for words in c:
  count=0
  for row in corpus:
    if words in row:
      count=count+1
  a.append(count)
```

Comment: yes got it, a small mistake ,Thank you so much, actually I am new in python, Thanks Mr. furas

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be functional.

```
from collections import Counter

words = []
for corp in corpus:
    words.extend(corp.split())

word_counts = Counter(words)

word_counts_list = []
for word in c:
    if word not in word_counts:
        word_counts_list.append(0)
    else:
        word_counts_list.append(word_counts[word])
```

Not the result you were expecting but the result you were expecting is not correct.

```
word_counts_list
Out[136]: [1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4]
```